# How to convert DataFrame to PairRdd

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I'm a spark beginner. I've a DataFrame like below, and I want to convert into a Pair RDD[(String, String)]. Appreciate any input.

```
DataFrame:
    col1 col2 col3 
    1     2    3
    4     5    6
Pair RDD:    
    (col1, 1)
    (col2, 2)
    (col3, 3)
    (col1, 4)
    (col2, 5)
    (col3, 6)
```

Comment: Can you explain the use case a bit in detail. Dataset and Dataframes can be very handy , just trying to see why you would need a pairRDD

Comment: I'm getting data from another source as pair rdd, and want to union both.

Answer (score 1):

Use df.map  to convert the df to a RDD if you want to map a row to a different RDD.

```
df.map(row => (row(1), row(2)))
```